# How to add dynamically growing array into another dynamic array

Tags: javascript

In my project i have arrays for date1, date2 and so on upto one month dates as shown below

```
var day1= [4,5,6,11];
var day2= [7,8,9,12];
var day3= [10,11,12,14];...

var day30= [1,2, 3, 4];
```

In the above each array exact size we dont know that may increase or decrease and i need to pass these values to the one more set of arrays like

```
var data1= [day1[0], day2[0], day3[0]];
var data2= [day1[1], day2[1], day3[1]];
var data3= [day1[2], day2[2], day3[2]];...

var data30= [day1[30], day2[30], day3[30]];
```

As per the day array size data array size will increase.

How to solve this issue any help..?

Comment: 10 question 0 accepted answer.............

Comment: instead of `day1..day30` you could use arrays. Array of arrays

Comment: your question is not very clear
If you have problem with arraysize then try using arrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an object instead of variables:

```
var days = {
  day1: [4,5,6,11],
  day2: [7,8,9,12],
  ... 
  day30: [1,2, 3, 4]
};
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var data30 = [];
var i = 0;
while ( days.hasOwnProperty('day' + ++i) ){
  data30.push(days['day' + i]);
}
```

Though given the sample data, `data30` won't have any members because the first array has no member at index `30`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JavaScript's push method.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp
```

Comment: Please don't reference [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/), reference the [appropriate specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.7) (W3C for DOM or ECMAScript for pure language items) and MSDN or MDN if examples seem useful.

Comment: ref: http://w3fools.com/  for why w3schools might not be the best reference to link to.